# Is it possible to customize swiping gesture recognition that triggers UIScrollView scroll?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uiscrollview

I've created a custom subclass from `UIScrollView` and implemented the `touchesBegan`, `touchesMoved`, `touchesEnded` and `touchesCancelled` methods.

However I'm not satisfied how things work. Particularly, when are mentioned methods getting called and when does `UIScrollView` decide to actually scroll(drag).

`UIScrollView` scrolls even if the difference between first touch point and last touch point is very little in vertical direction. So I can swipe almost horizontally and `UIScrollView` is going to scroll up or down depending on that small difference.(Which is perfectly fine in normal use cases)

[image: Default UIScrollView behavior]

Both of these swipes would cause `UIScrollView` to scroll downwards.

However I'm interested would it be possible to adjust it somehow, so that it behaves like this:

[image: Desired behavior]

Basically so that near horizontal swiping gets picked up by `touchesBegan` and related methods and does not initiate scroll. The green swiping direction would however still initiate scrolling...

EDIT:

I forgot to mention, `touchesBegan` and relatives do get called if you hold your finger for a short period of time on the screen and then move it around. So not a classical swiping gesture...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Christopher Nassar correctly pointed out that I should be using `UIPanGestureRecognizer`, so I experimented a bit with it.

What I found out is that if you add a `UIPanGestureRecognizer` to the *superview* that contains your `UIScrollView`. Then the `UIScrollView` built in pan gesture recognizer is going to work in pair with your own `UIPanGestureRecognizer` in the exact manner that I desired!

Horizontal and near horizontal swipes are going to be picked up by the `UIPanGestureRecognizer` of the *superview* and all other vertical ones by the `UIScrollView` (custom) built in pan gesture recognizer and cause it to scroll...

I suppose that `UIScrollView` has been designed that way, because the default behavior would be that only one of these pan gesture recognizers triggers, or both simultaneously if `UIScrollView` returns YES from this `UIPanGestureRecognizerDelegate` method:

```
- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)otherGestureRecognizer;
```

However it seems that `UIScrollView` has additional logic to selectively disable(for horizontal swipes) its own pan recognizer in case another one exists.

Maybe someone here knows more details about that.

So to sum it up the solution for me was to add a `UIPanGestureRecognizer` inside `viewDidLoad` in my `UIViewController`.(Note: `UIScrollView` is added as a *subview* to that `UIViewController` view)

```
UIPanGestureRecognizer *myPanGestureRecognizer = [[UIPanGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handlePan:)];
[self.view addGestureRecognizer:myPanGestureRecognizer];
```

and then add the handler method:

```
- (void)handlePan:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)recognizer
{
    NSLog(@"Swiped horizontally...");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Ivan, I think you are trying to do the same effect as Facebook page is, and drag your scrollview , so letting the scrollview follow your finger, if that is correct, I suggest that you forget about touches events, and start with UIPanGesture , its the best in these cases, so inside the delegate that calls that gesture, put the following code for it:

```
    //The sender view, in your case the scollview
    UIScrollView* scr = (UIScrollView*)sender.view;
    //Disable the scrolling flag for the sake of user experience
    [scr setScrollEnabled:false];

    //Get the current translation point of the scrollview in respect to the main view
    CGPoint translation = [sender translationInView:self.view];

    //Set the view center to the new translation point 
    float translationPoint = scr.center.x + translation.x;
    scr.center = CGPointMake(translationPoint,scr.center.y);
    [sender setTranslation:CGPointMake(0, 0) inView:self.view];
```

Comment: Good point! I've just tried the Facebook app and that's seems to be that .. if you swipe left or right, the news feed(presumably a UIScrollView) slides to the side... I'm going to try your suggestion now. However I must note that I'm actually not trying to open side menus but actually change the value of an NSInteger variable (increase/decrease) with regard to horizontal swiping or dragging...